# I need to add hover on a link inside a list css

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a link inside a ul li list and i'm trying to add a hover, but it's not working. Any ideas?
HTML:

```css
.info ul a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.bay42.io" class="arrow1">
        <p>Learn about our technology<span class="arrow-left"></p></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://www.bay42.io/careers" class="arrow1">
        <p>Careers<span class="arrow-right"></p></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, as far as I can see

Comment: It works with the code that you have supplied. It might be something else on your page that is breaking it then.

Comment: It's working. Maybe your you have multiple css for same dom. Try to put !important like this color: black !important; and see if it work

Answer (score -1):

maybe u overwrite this style or u put it in wrong order ?!
**remember** : a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS definition in order to be effective! a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order to be effective! Pseudo-class names are not case-sensitive.